# php code showing up in <td>

Tags: php

i have a log file which is filed with errors and sadly i don't know php :( in order to fix my problems. The following line should let me input a value for a subnet from what i understand

```
 <td>Subnet Filter:<input name=subnet value=<?php=isset($subnet)?$subnet:"0.0.0.0/0"?>>
```

but when i check the web page to input my value the textbox has the following text in it :`<?php=isset($subnet)?$subnet:"0.0.0.0/0"?`. Could anyone explain to me what is going on, or where should i look for answers. Also is this syntax specific to php4? because i'm using php5 and the whole page is full of errors, and it's a downloaded application so it should have worked from the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use short tags for this:

```
<?=isset($subnet)?$subnet:"0.0.0.0/0"?>
```

Or if you can't then:

```
<?php echo isset($subnet)?$subnet:"0.0.0.0/0"; ?>
```

You can't echo with = with `<?php` tag. It has to be `<?=` or `<?php echo`

Comment: @AVD - Not recommending, just saying that's where they've gone wrong. On this note I've only ever had one server with short tags turned off in 6 years of PHP site building.

Comment: @AVD Actually, since 5.4 short tags will *always* be on.

Comment: @Jack - Really? That would explain that then. Thanks.

Comment: @AVD in your own link there are lots of people recommending short tags

Answer (score 0):

error in your line it should be

```
<?php isset($subnet)?$subnet:"0.0.0.0/0"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem 1

If you are seeing PHP code on your page then you probably don't have PHP installed and configured on your server correctly. Address this before trying to tackle coding issues.

---

### Problem 2

You need to echo a value

```
<?php echo somecode(); ?>
```

---

### Problem 3

HTML value attributes need quotes around them

```
<input name="subnet" value="<?php echo isset($subnet)?$subnet:"0.0.0.0/0"; ?>">
                           ^ start here                             end here ^
```

I would also like to point out that just because you downloaded a PHP app from somewhere on the internet, doesn't mean it should work right out of the box, or that it is error free.

Comment: I totally agree with you, that is why i had to recompile php with suport for postgresql, and load the php5 module in the my apache server. I have tested with phpinfo and a short php script which showed some values from the database and it works, so basically i thought my job was done. The rest should be handled by the code or at least that was my opinion.

Comment: @primero if you have verified the PHP is working on the server, then try changing the line of code to as suggested in my answer, and re-run the code.

Comment: i did it and it works, thanks for the suggestion :). The thing is i have a lot of errors that is why i was asking about php versions.

Comment: @primero that code is not specific to any PHP version, it will work on both php4 and php5. What other errors are you getting? To be honest, if you downloaded the product and it had that error in it, it's probably not a quality product, or at least not been tested properly. As a customer/user of software, when you find yourself finding and fixing lots of coding errors then it could be time to choose another product.

Comment: It is the code for the webapp of BandwidthD, when using the database installation. The program works in it's default installation because it uses only html and it's really easy to configure and the output rendered by it is really compact. There are not many programs that can substitute it. And i just can't believe that they gave such poor php code for the webapp.